# how to setup apache2 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, kubuntu, apache2, webserver

I know there are already question like this. However i have different problem. Apache2 was working properly on my system. But to do configurations of twiki from start i deleted directory `/etc/apache2` and  `/var/www` and then i remove and uninstall apache2 from my system.
So now when i tried to install apache2 again using command `sudo apt install apache2` i am facing this error

[image]

Following image is the output of command `ls -l /var | grep www` suggested by George Udosen
[image]

Comment: Please recreate that folder `sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html` and try the installation again

Comment: above suggestion is not solving my problem

Comment: run `ls -l /var | grep www` and post the results

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I posted results. please check

Comment: now remove it with `sudo purge apache2` and re-add

Comment: @HaiderYaqoob, Try reinstalling all its packages using: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils` , ref: package info here https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apache2